# For a Brownian motion, what is the probability that $B(t)$ 'hits' $a$ before it hits $b$, for given $a < 0 < b$?

Tags: stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

My attempt:

Let $X_1,X_2,\ldots $ be iid random variables with $P[X_i =-1] = P[X_i=1] = \frac12$. If we let $S _n =\sum_{i=1}^n X_i$, then for integer $a< 0< b$, the probability that $S_n$ hits $a$ before $b$ is $\frac{b}{b+|a|}$. This is the classic gamblers ruin problem. Define now $\hat{S}_n(t)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \sum_{i=1}^{\lfloor{tn \rfloor}} X_i$. If $n$ is a square such that $\sqrt{n}a$ and $\sqrt{n}b$ are integers, then
$$ P[ \hat{S}_n \text{ hits $a$ before $b$}] = P[ S_n \text{ hits $\sqrt{n}a$ before $\sqrt{n}b$}  ]   = \frac{b}{|a|+b} $$
again. Such $n$ of course exist only when $a,b$ are rational. Now, I know that in some sense $\hat{S}_n(t)$ converges to $B(t)$ (a standard Brownian motion) as $n\to \infty$, so I'm quite sure the answer should be $\frac{b}{|a|+b}$ also for the Brownian motion $B(t)$. But I am not sure how to plug the following two holes:

- Even if $B(t)$ and $\hat{S}_n(t)$ are close, $\hat{S}_n(t)$ may come close to $b$ before hitting $a$, and then $B(t)$ may actually sneakily hit $b$ by diverging slightly from $\hat{S}_n(t)$.
- What about when $a$, $b$ are irrational?